# including functions in seperate file in arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, include

Noob qn.

I was using Arduino 1.6.5 and I had something like below that used to work.

main.ino

```
#include "oldFunctions.h"

#define BLAHBLAH
setup(){
  //....
}
loop(){
  //....
}


void newFunctionA(void){
//....
}
```

oldFunctions.h. This is a file I added over time, with new functions and stuff.

```
void test(void){
   newFunctionA();
}
```

This used to work in Arduino 1.6.5, but I upgraded to 1.6.8 and now I get the error saying newFunctionA was not declared in this scope

Can someone help?

Comment: This doesn't look like valid C. Please copy exactly what you're using. Is the missing quotes on the include deliberate? Also is this a typo oldFunctions.h != oldfunctions.h

Comment: Try putting `void newFunctionA(void);` on the line before `void test(void){`.

Comment: Arduino is actually C++, even if it doesn't look like that. Please change the flags.

Comment: @Harry Sorry it was a typo. I have updated it. The actual code is a bit too long, thats why I just put an example. I have a .ino file, and 2 .h files, one of which is the oldFunctions.h. This has functions, as well as calls to functions that are defined in the .ino file.

Comment: @user3386109 I tried that. The fact is, I have a bunch of files which are throwing errors. When I add void newFunctionA(void), that error goes away, and the next function throws an error. Once I finish adding definitions of all such functions, then it start giving the error, duplicate definition of newFunctionA()

Comment: Without seeing the whole picture, it's hard to say what's wrong. The change in behavior between 1.6.5 and 1.6.8 is probably due to stricter enforcement of prototyping. The new version of the C specification states that a function call may not appear without a prior function prototype (note that the function definition can serve as the prototype). In the past, the compiler would make assumptions about the function prototype if the prototype was not given. But now it's up to the programmer to make sure every function has a prototype.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's ALWAYS a bad idea messing up with the files and then hoping that the compiler does some magic. What I suggest you is to use the files as they are meant to be used, so

- Header files (`*.h`, `*.hpp`) shall contain class definitions (but not implementations), global variables defined as `extern`, function prototypes. They shall use the common `ifndef...` to prevent multiple inclusions
- Source files (`*.c`, `*.cpp`, `*.ino`) shall contain the actual function implementations, the methods implementations, and the global variables definitions.

You should not avoid using this, otherwise you will enter a lot of possible troubles.

In your case, you should then have three files:

**main.ino**

```
#include "oldFunctions.h"

#define BLAHBLAH
setup(){
  //....
}
loop(){
  //....
}

void newFunctionA(void){
//....
}
```

**oldFunctions.h**

```
#ifndef OLD_FUNCTIONS_H
#define OLD_FUNCTIONS_H

void newFunctionA();
void test();

#endif
```

**oldFunctions.cpp**

```
#include "oldFunctions.h"

void test(void){
    newFunctionA();
}
```

Please note, however, that in the cpp file you should not use the `BLAHBLAH` you defined in `main.ino`. If you need it, move it to the `oldfunctions.h` file.

In `newFunctionA` is a new function you want to keep separated from the oldfunctions, just create a new header file and include it. The important part is that you do not rely on arduino joining the source files, because this can lead to unexpected behavior.